# Trouble converting data retrieved from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble downcasting data received from firebase to collection type. I would really appreciate any help making me understand what i missed or did wrong.

[image: Firebase Structure][FirebaseStructure]

My Function:

```
func configureDatabase() {
        self.rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        rootRef.child("user1/week1/MON/").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let snap = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
                let fetchedObject = snap.value
                //This results <AnyObject>
                print(fetchedObject.dynamicType)

})

}
```

When I am trying to convert the fetchedObject into Dictionary of type [String: AnyObject] or [String: String] -

```
 let fetchedObject = snap.value as! Dictionary[String: AnyObject]
```

it throws an error - 
**Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1043e5090) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1043e5d60).**

Here is the console output of print(fetchedObject) if it can be of any help:

```
Optional({
    medicine = Azithromycin;
    time = 0700;
})
Optional({
    medicine = Azithromycin;
    time = 1800;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok! I solved the issue! Performed a clean operation, then                 changed firebase database persistence to false which was true before.

```
 FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = false
```

This solved the issue! Apparently the app was loading the data from cache i guess, so i wasn't getting the correct data.